# Loading modules in python vs. ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to convert an ipython notebook to a python file and execute it.
In the file I have:

```
from multifit.datasets import ULMFiTDataset, Dataset
from multifit import ULMFiT, multifit1552_fp16, multifit1552_fp32
```

The directory structure of my files is like:

```
multifit\
   datasets\
notebooks\
   notebook.ipython
   notebook.py
```

I have no problem for loading the modules in the converted notebook (`notebook.py`) using `ipython` command, but if I use `python` I recieve error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml.py", line 27, in <module>
    from multifit.datasets import ULMFiTDataset, Dataset
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multifit'
```

In general, how can I load the modules with python based on the mentioned file structure?

Also I manually commented or converted the following section:

```
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('env', 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1')
import os    
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="1"

# In[2]:


#get_ipython().run_line_magic('reload_ext', 'autoreload')
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('autoreload', '2')
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
#get_ipython().run_line_magic('cd', '..')
os.chdir('..')

from fastai.text import *
from multifit.datasets import ULMFiTDataset, Dataset
from multifit import ULMFiT, multifit1552_fp16, multifit1552_fp32
```

Comment: Hey, could tell us more about your python and ipython version ?  For example, when your run `import sys; print(sys.executable)`, do you get identical results ?

Comment: @GrégoireRoussel python 3.7.6 and sys prints `/home/ahmad/miniconda3/bin/python`

Comment: Are you sure about your directory structure?  For debugging, add `print(os.getcwd())` before the `import` line.

Comment: @Ahmad so I assume you checked that is the same path in ipython (it could very well not be, Ipython is another executable, it tries to detect your python but might fail). 
You might face a bad current working directory (as @Jerry says): to have multifit findable, you must start python from your root folder, or prepend your imports with a `sys.path.append("..")", or even give the absolute path. Indeed, python by default adds the current directory in the list of searchable path, ipython might have something more clever. `print(sys.path)` in both interpreters and check for differences to see.

Answer (score 0):

Python may be interpreting the top of your package to be the notebook folder, so absolute imports are failing.

Have you tried relative imports?

```py
from ..multifit.datasets import ULMFiTDataset, Dataset
from ..multifit import ULMFiT, multifit1552_fp16, multifit1552_fp32
```

Comment: it gives `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`